# Noise reduction in Adobe Camera Raw

Tags: raw, noise, noise-reduction, adobe, noise-removal

When I open a raw file shot in ISO 1600 in ACR there is very little noise in the photo. But after color adjustments when i save or export as a JPG file there is much more noise visible. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Have you increased contrast? Have you applied sharpening/ Have you increased exposure/brightness/saturation/vibrance/clarity? All of these things will increase the amount of noise you can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael has some good suggestions. You can also try

1. Saving as a PNG (I've always found to be a better format at retaining details)
2. In Camera RAW, zoom in to 1:1 magnification and see if the noise is present.

On the other hand, you are using ISO 1600 which produces noisy images on certain camera models.

If you want to reduce noise in ACR just go into sharpness and increase noise reduction, although this will make you lose sharpness. In the past, if I've wanted to apply some noise reduction on a RAW image, I've used the adjustment brush and manually added the areas I want fixed. For example, I might want the sky to be less noisy but the hills and trees to retain their detail.

Comment: Not sure I 100% agree about the iso 1600 meaning noise in inevitable unless you're shooting prosumer. I shot [this image](https://www.flickr.com/photos/inkista/94890647) at iso 1600 with a 2005 entry-level dSLR (Canon 350D). It's a SOOC JPEG (no post processing).

Comment: Very nice picture! :-) I'm just going off past experiences, I use Sony SLTs and the a77 had horrific noise at 1600. Since we don't have a picture that the OP was referring to I can not for certain see the severity of the noise for myself

Comment: @inkista I'm sure you know that a high ISO setting is not the thing contributing to noise - it's the low level of the input signal.